# Run flutter app in debug mode in xiaomi phone

Tags: android, flutter, dart, xiaomi

i just wanted debug my flutter app on xiaomi x4Pro phone and other xiaomi phone but this
error occurred :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on 2201116PG in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\code\FL\redo remaster\redo\build\app\outputs\flutter- 
apk\app.apk: 
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]
Error launching application on 2201116PG.

Exited (sigterm)
```

but when i run app in Samsung phone everything goes fine .

Comment: When you try to install a Flutter app to Xiaomi phones before installation starts you should accept the prompt that pop up on the screen. If you don't Install canceled by user error throws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options ->
2. Turn On "USB Debugging"
3. Turn On "Install via USB"
4. And accept the permission to install the app in the mobile during the instalation.